# How to make a for loop that has two variables that are equal to each other?

Tags: bash, loops, for-loop

I have two lists of variables that are equal to each other and I am trying to make a bash script in order to put both of these subject variable name files into one folder:

Here is an example of the list of variables:

```
az100 ms200 #first subject
az101 ma600 #second subject
```

where I want `az100 == ms200 == ${SUBJECT}`

```
for SUBJECT in az100
do
    dicoms=${SUBJECT}/dicoms
    rsync -aP /path/${SUBJECT}/ "$dicoms"
done
```

I know that I could manually do this, but I was wondering what the most elegant and efficient way to make two variables equal to each other in a for loop?

here is an example of what I have tried:

```
for SUBJECT in az100 az200 az300

        rsync -aP /path/${SUBJECT}/* /path/${SUBJECT}/dicoms

    for SUBJ_MR_CODE in mz100 mz200 mz300
        do
        rsync -aP /path/${SUB_MR_CODE}/* /path/${SUBJECT}/dicoms
    
        done
        done
```

However, this seems like a risky approach, and I want to make sure there are error codes if az100 doesn't equal mz100 for example.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean. Can you show what you "can do manually" so we can understand what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: I'm also not sure what you mean by _"lists of veriables"_

Comment: Thank you! sorry I am new at this! I have subject 1. Subject 1 has two different code names: az100 and ms200. I have two directories that have files in them that I want to copy and do the same things to: az100/file ms200/file. I want to be able to move all these files in both directories to a common folder. I want to make the SUBJECT variable equal to both az100 and ms200 and make sure that I am never accidentally coupling az100 with a different ms variable e.g. ms300.

Comment: I have a very long list of subject names where each row has two subject codes that are equal to first, second, third, subjects.

Comment: How to make two variables equal to each other: `var1="$var2"`.  You can put that assignment inside a `for` loop.  I do not understand the rest of your question.